# File seen on desktop but not in the command line

Tags: 16.04, command-line

I used Kate text editor to create a file called `new_email_accounts.txt` which I saved on my desktop, but from the screenshot below another file was created too called `new_email_accounts.txt.rw4960`
[image: desktop screenshot]

Problem is, when I run the `ls -la` command in the terminal I cannot see the file as seen in the screenshot below
[image: ls -la screenshot]

And another issue is, when I try to delete the file using <kbd>delete</kbd> key or a combination of <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> keys, I get an error as shown below
[image: error deleting file]

I have also noticed this behavior quite often usually when I download files from my browsers; they seem to create another copy of the file downloaded with added extension for example `.crwdownload`, which is (or are) automatically removed after rebooting or logging off.

What could be the cause of all this behavior and can it be mitigated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try saving your text file and then closing down your text editor, Kate, completely and then look for your file in command line again.  It should be there.

The temp file with extra extension will probably disappear when you save your file or close your text editor, Kate  (or when the downloading from your web browser is finished).

Comment: when i close the text editor the file `new_email_accounts.txt.rw4960` does disappear but for the files downloaded using any of my browsers, the file with the unusual extension doesn't disappear even after closing the browser. My guess it's glitch in the ubuntu desktop system somewhere but thanks for the help anywhere

Comment: @kellymandem I appreciate it if you click on the check mark right by the answer you found most helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

This most likely means the temp file doesn't actually exist anymore, it's just a graphical glitch.

Try "refreshing" your desktop by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.